# Trying to plot DataFrame with matplotlib, double entries in legend, and no y axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame with five columns: Time, Mean, STD, Min and Max.

I am trying to create a plot which shows three lines, Mean, Min and Max, and the STD to show as a shaded area around Mean. It works, but I am hitting an issue where the y-label does not show, and the legend entries are doubled up, apart from the STD. The problem seems to be with the plt.plot's as when I comment out the three plt.plot's the resulting plt.fill has the y-label and a legend with one entry. Here's (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKkd0.jpg) the plot.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('data_all_1.txt', delimiter=',')

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close()

data = pd.DataFrame(my_data,columns=['Frame', 'Mean', 'STD', 'Min', 'Max'])


plt.plot(data.loc[:10,'Frame'], data.loc[:10,'Mean'], '#1f78b4','-', label='Mean temperature')
plt.fill_between(data['Frame'], data['Mean'] - data['STD'], data['Mean'] + data['STD'], facecolor='#a6cee3', label='Standard deviation')
plt.plot(data['Frame'], data['Min'],'#b2df8a' ,'-', label='Minimum temperature')
plt.plot(data['Frame'], data['Max'], '#33a02c','-', label='Maximum temperature')
plt.xlabel('Time, minutes')
plt.ylabel('Temperature $^\circ$C')
plt.legend(loc='lower right') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyplot.plot takes arguments as

```
plot([x], y, [fmt], data=None, **kwargs)
```

So, the problem is in your [fmnt] which should be in this '[color][marker][line]'
By default, if a [line] is given, but no [marker], the data will be a line without markers
You can simply remove '-', so it becomes

```
plt.plot(data.loc[:10,'Frame'], data.loc[:10,'Mean'], '#1f78b4', label='Mean temperature')
```

If you really need to include both line style and the color (in hex), you need explicitly specify them in the arguments as

```
plt.plot(x, y, color='#1f78b4', linestyle='-', label='...')
```

Otherwise, hex-string color is only allowed when color is the only thing specified in '[color][marker][line]' argument